# Ripping hidden title in extras on a dvd

Tags: dvd

I have a children's dvd which has 13 chapters, but the 13th chapter is only accessible through the dvd menu when you answer 10 questions correctly - and I can't find a way to rip it.

I don't want the quiz, just the episode.

When I rip the whole dvd, the file for chapter 13 that is written to the hard drive has only a few kilobytes and won't play in VLC.

I'm using handbrake and have also tried dvd::rip and omgrip. How can I get that 13th chapter?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a new DVD player and it can read the "invisible" chapter :)

It's the Apple USB DVD player which my partner got with her new Mac.